# SSL_accept appears to block for 15 seconds

Tags: multithreading, ssl, openssl

I have an SSL server, which has, suddenly stopped processing client requests.

I see the following error.

> > SSL_GET_NEW_SESSION:ssl session id callback failed.

My observations so far:

The `SSL_accept` returns (the socket is non-blocking) exactly after 15 seconds.

The following code indicates the throwing up of the error "callback failure for session id" in generating session-id.

```
        CRYPTO_r_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK_SSL_CTX);
    if(s->generate_session_id)
        cb = s->generate_session_id;
    else if(s->session_ctx->generate_session_id)
        cb = s->session_ctx->generate_session_id;
    CRYPTO_r_unlock(CRYPTO_LOCK_SSL_CTX);
    /* Choose a session ID */
    tmp = ss->session_id_length;
    if(!cb(s, ss->session_id, &tmp))
        {
        /* The callback failed */
        SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_GET_NEW_SESSION,
            SSL_R_SSL_SESSION_ID_CALLBACK_FAILED);
        SSL_SESSION_free(ss);
        return(0);
        }
```

There is a thread lock and release after which the exception is thrown. Could it be that obtaining of the crypto lock fails and is timing out (hazarding a guess here)?

What could cause `SSL_accept` delayed return?

Otherwise, the session-id callback failure, I understand to be due to issues in generating "random" for the session-id. What could go wrong here?

Comment: Assuming all other things are correct, it sounds like you may need to either (1) restart your server; or (2) recompile your server to use the latest OpenSSL sources provided by the distro. For (2) the OpenSSL shared object may have changed.

Comment: @jww, yes application restart did fix the issue. But I am afraid, it might re-occur.Any thoughts on the 15 seconds timeout? Exactly 15 seconds, **each time**? I am clueless as to why application ended up in this state.

Comment: I'm guessing one of two things... (1) an unintentional ABI break (i.e., structure layout has changed); or (2) a memory error in the program. Either one could have corrupted state and unintentionally reconfigured a socket. If it was an ABI change, you may have gotten lucky by reloading the shared objects. If its a memory error and you get lucky, then you will get a crash to get a toehold on things.